# Finding the edges of a board in a 3D point cloud with python

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, camera-calibration, open3d

I have a point cloud containing a checkerboard pattern, and my task is to identify the edges of the checkerboard within the cloud. I have successfully extracted the plane on which the board is located using Open3D. However, I am stuck at detecting the board's edges. What would be the most effective approach to achieve this?

I tried using [this](https://github.com/denabazazian/Edge_Extraction), but the result isn't what I'm expecting, even if I change the hyperparameters.
I've also tried to extract the checkerboard with matlab, by using the [detectRectangularPlanePoints](https://it.mathworks.com/help/lidar/ref/detectrectangularplanepoints.html) function, but it's not able to find it.